# Spark higher order functions to compute top N products from a comma separated list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 2.4 and I have a spark dataframe that has 2 columns - `id` and `product_list`. The data consists of list of products that every `id` has interacted with.

here is the sample code -

```
scala> spark.version
res3: String = 2.4.3

val df = Seq(
("1", "p1,p1,p1,p1,p1,p3,p3,p2,p2,p2,p2"),
("2", "p2,p2,p2,p2,p2,p4,p4,p4,p1,p3")
).toDF("id", "product_list")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")


+---+--------------------------------+
|id |product_list                    |
+---+--------------------------------+
|1  |p1,p1,p1,p1,p1,p3,p3,p2,p2,p2,p2|
|2  |p2,p2,p2,p2,p2,p4,p4,p4,p1,p3   |
+---+--------------------------------+
```

I would like to return those `top 2` products that every `id` has had a interaction with. For instance, `id = 1` has viewed products `p1 - 5 times` and `p2 - 4 times`, so i would like to return `p1,p2` for `id = 1`. Similarly, `p2,p4` for `id = 2`.

My final output should look like

```
id, most_seen_products
1, p1,p2
2, p2,p4
```

Since I am using Spark 2.4, I was wondering if there is a higher order function to first convert this list to array and then return the top 2 viewed products. In general the code should handle `top N` products.

Comment: first of all, for the Higher-order function data frame column must be in an array and your data frame seems me to string type. so I would suggest you to update data frame first.

Comment: Is there a specific Spark API you want to use (Dataset/DataFrame/RDD)? The function to convert a comma-delimited string to an array already exists, it's called `split` (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/#split). Your `topN` implementation would depend on which Spark API you want to use (they'd be very similar though).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach

```
  val df = Seq(
      ("1", "p1,p1,p1,p1,p1,p3,p3,p2,p2,p2,p2"),
      ("2", "p2,p2,p2,p2,p2,p4,p4,p4,p1,p3")
    ).toDF("id", "product_list")


 def getMetrics(value: Row, n: Int): (String, String) = {

    val split = value.getAs[String]("product_list").split(",")

    val sortedRecords = split.groupBy(x => x).map(data => (data._1, data._2.size)).toList.sortWith(_._2 > _._2)
    (value.getAs[String]("id"), sortedRecords.take(n).map(_._1).mkString(","))

  }


   df.map(value =>
      getMetrics(value, 2)
    ).withColumnRenamed("_1", "id").withColumnRenamed("_2", "most_seen_products") show (false)
```

**Result**

```
+---+------------------+
|id |most_seen_products|
+---+------------------+
|1  |p1,p2             |
|2  |p2,p4             |
+---+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your data format, you can just use a .map() or in case of SQL, a UDF, which converts all rows. The function will be:

```
productList => {
    // list of products = split productList by comma
    // add all items to a String/Count map
    // sort the map, get first 2 elements
    // return string.join of those 2 elements
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
scala> import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap
scala> def max_products:UserDefinedFunction = udf((product:String) => {
val productList = product.split(",").toList
val finalList = ListMap(productList.groupBy(i=>i).mapValues(_.size).toSeq.sortWith(_._2 > _._2):_*).keys.toList
finalList(0) + "," + finalList(1)
})

scala> df.withColumn("most_seen_products", max_products(col("product_list"))).show(false)
+---+--------------------------------+------------------+
|id |product_list                    |most_seen_products|
+---+--------------------------------+------------------+
|1  |p1,p1,p1,p1,p1,p3,p3,p2,p2,p2,p2|p1,p2             |
|2  |p2,p2,p2,p2,p2,p4,p4,p4,p1,p3   |p2,p4             |
+---+--------------------------------+------------------+
```